# Hyperledger multi-orderer HA within single organisation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

We are trying to deploy High Availability ordering service, but faced with errors.

The configuration of hyperledger-fabric is:

First VM (192.168.1.5):

- CA
- couchdb
- orderer0
- peer0 (connected to orderer0)
- peer1 (connected to orderer0)
- kafka
- zookeeper

Second VM (192.168.1.6):

- couchdb
- orderer1
- peer2 (connected to orderer1)
- peer3 (connected to orderer1)

There are no errors, and using composer-playground on these two VMs we can successfully create New Participant (as example) on First VM and check it on Second.

When I stop orderer0 on First VM (192.168.1.5) I'm getting an error on both VMs:

```
Error: Error trying invoke business network. Error: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
```

Orderer1 log (VM2):

```
2018-10-30 13:32:34.427 UTC [couchdb] CreateDatabaseIfNotExist -> INFO 03d   Created state database composerchannel_sp
2018-10-30 13:32:38.348 UTC [cceventmgmt] HandleStateUpdates -> INFO 03e Channel [composerchannel]: Handling LSCC state update for chaincode [sp]
2018-10-30 13:32:38.398 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 03f Created CouchDB index [selectDocumentsByRepo] in state database [composerchannel_sp] using design document [_design/selectDocumentsByRepoDoc]
2018-10-30 13:32:38.405 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 040 Channel [composerchannel]: Committed block [1] with 1 transaction(s)
2018-10-30 13:32:38.458 UTC [common/deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 041 [channel: composerchannel] Error sending to 192.168.1.5:57178: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = the stream has been done
2018-10-30 13:32:59.971 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 042 Channel [composerchannel]: Committed block [2] with 1 transaction(s)
2018-10-30 13:32:59.991 UTC [common/deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 043 [channel: composerchannel] Error sending to 192.168.1.5:57198: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = the stream has been done
2018-10-30 13:35:43.340 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 044 Channel [composerchannel]: Committed block [3] with 1 transaction(s)
2018-10-30 13:35:43.386 UTC [common/deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 045 [channel: composerchannel] Error sending to 192.168.1.5:57458: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = the stream has been done
2018-10-30 13:35:43.386 UTC [common/deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 046 [channel: composerchannel] Error sending to 192.168.1.5:57430: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = the stream has been done
2018-10-30 13:35:43.386 UTC [common/deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 047 [channel: composerchannel] Error sending to 192.168.1.5:57448: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = the stream has been done
2018-10-30 13:35:56.150 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 048 Channel [composerchannel]: Committed block [4] with 1 transaction(s)
```

composer-playground console output(VM2):

```
(node:20567) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:20567) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to receive commit notification from 192.168.1.5:8051 for transaction 'a6ea73f6cf24d8e4cca5ee7ab273d417b6dfd9abfd2f027afeda5dd60538c4ce' within the timeout period
```

As I thought all orderer instances have all data of each other if they are working using Kafka or I'm wrong?